# How to deal with 3 times quotation marks in a onclick proberty of an element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a little problem: In my project I tried to make a like button and defined a button attached to a function via onclick proberty. But now it looks like this:

```
<div class="post-container">
    <button class="{% if post.liked %}color-blue{% else %}color-white{% endif %}" id="post_{{ post.id|stringformat:'s' }}" onclick="postLike('{{ post.id|stringformat:'s' }}')"> {{ number_of_likes }} Like{{ number_of_likes|pluralize }}</button>
</div>
```

Visual Studio Code red-marks this and I am not really sure how to handle these this, since I am getting an error on onclick in the Console when I press the button...

Comment: whtat's the double `{{` ??

Comment: Are you using any JS framework?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I am using Jquery...

Answer (score 1):

To deal with 3 times quotation marks you need to switch between single and double quotes. Try doing this:

```
onclick='postLike("{{ post.id|stringformat:'s' }}")'
```

Comment: but... not getting the SAME error anymore.

Comment: Maybe this: `onclick='postLike("{ post.id|stringformat:'s' }")'`

Comment: You also can use only `onclick="postLike()"` and call `function postLike()` on JavaScript. It is more usual.

Comment: I am sorry, now I read you are using jQuery. Anyway, I believe I answered your doubt about how to deal with 3 quotation marks, didn't I?

Answer (score 1):

Inline handlers like you're currently using are universally considered to be terrible practice, and one of the reasons for that is because they have very ugly quote escaping problems when passing string parameters. (They also require global pollution and have a demented scope chain.)

Put the post ID into a data attribute instead, and attach listeners to each element in standalone JavaScript elsewhere. For example, if you're starting with

```
<button class="myButton" onclick="postLike('{{ post.id|stringformat:'s' }}')">
```

change to

```
<button class="myButton" data-post-id="{{ post.id|stringformat:'s' }}">
```

and retrieve the post ID from the button when clicked. After the HTML contains all the buttons, run the following JS:

```
for (const button of document.querySelectorAll('.myButton')) {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    postLike(e.target.dataset.postId);
  });
}
```

You will have to tweak the selector string `.myButton` depending on the HTML markup around your buttons.

Another option, using event delegation on a container of all the buttons:

```
container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.dataset.postId) {
    postLike(e.target.dataset.postId);
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok... I am using th first method, but the button click isn't recognized.

Comment: Did you remember to tweak the selector string as the answer says? What it will be depends on the HTML markup around the button, but you haven't included it in your question.

Comment: Ok... the problem is that the class is depending on whether the post is liked or not... so can I just copy and paste the whole statements including the classes like this: `{% if post.liked %}color-blue{% else %}color-white{% endif %}` or what...?

Comment: If the classes are too dynamic, identify the elements by looking at the parent instead. Eg if you have `<div class="post-container"><button` you can select children of the container by `.post-container button`.

Comment: it's still not working... maybe because the object has already an id (if there is no difference between data-post-id and id)?

Comment: If you can't figure it out, please post a decent section of the HTML around your buttons in your question. No, the dataset property is entirely different from the ID attribute